# String "returned" from function is broken, but "echo" works

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on my first Wordpress plug-in and it's been a lot of fun.

I was using echo to show HTML, but it was showing on the top of the page. Doing some digging, I found out that I should use "return" in the function. Switching to "return" is causing other issues. It looks like the string () I'm trying to output is being wrecked by "return". I can output the string using echo and it works (just in the wrong place).

Any thoughts?

```
function v3grid_func($atts) {

// Get the parameters from the shortcode
$atts = shortcode_atts(

    array(
        'count' => 3,
        'link_to_all' => 'yes',
        'css_class' => 'v3grid',
        'categories' => '1'
    ), $atts

);

// Get list of recent posts
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => $atts['count'],
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'include' => '',
    'exclude' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' =>'',
    //'post_type' => array('post', 'podcast', 'recipe', 'roundup'),
    'post_type' => array('roundup'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

// Figure out width requirement for each grid item
$width = 100/$atts[count];

$output = '';

// Container for row start
$output .=  'Start -> <div style="margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; box-sizing: border-box; position:relative; display:block;">';

// Loop through posts
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){

        // Get the URL of the feature image for the post
        $thumbnail = htmlentities(get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $recent["ID"], 'full' ));

        $url = htmlentities(get_permalink($recent["ID"]));
        $title = htmlentities($recent["post_title"]);

        $output .=  '   1 - <div style="width:'.$width.'%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">';
        $output .=  '       2 - <div><img src="'.$thumbnail.'" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>'; // <-- Problem likely here           
        $output .=  '       3 - <div><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></div>';
        $output .=  '   4 - </div>';

    }

// Container for row end
$output .=  'End -> </div>';

echo $output; // Shows everything as expected
return $output; // Does not show everything as expected (need to use return)

wp_reset_query();

}

add_shortcode('v3grid', 'v3grid_func');
```

Here is the output from both the echo and the return. I added to start, end, and numbers so I could trace the output. Thought it was a problem in my foreach.

An output using "echo" in function - output is good.

```
Start -> <div style="margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; box-sizing: border-box; position:relative; display:block;">    

1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/THUMBNAIL-150x150.jpg" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>     
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post1/">Post Title A</a></div>   
4 - </div>  

1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/THUMBNAIL-1-150x150.jpg" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>       
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post2/">Post Title B</a></div>   
4 - </div>  

1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/Thumbnail-Image-150x150.gif" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>       
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post3/">Post Title C</a></div>   
4 - </div>  

1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/SnacksTHUMBNAIL-150x150.jpg" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>       
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post4/">Post Title D</a></div>   
4 - </div>

End -> </div>
```

Output if using "return" in function - Output is bad/broken

Start ->

```
1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/THUMBNAIL-150x150.jpg" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>     
3 - <div></div>     
3 - <div></div>     
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post3/">Post Title C</div>   
4 - </div>  

1 - <div style="width:25%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">       
2 - <div><img src="/wp-content/uploads/SnacksTHUMBNAIL-150x150.jpg" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>       
3 - <div><a href="/roundup/post4/">Post Title D</div>   
4 - </div>

End -> </div>
```

Comment: is the method `wp_reset_query();` necessary? Because the return will prevent/stop the execution and echo doesn't.

Comment: Hi @GabrielHeming thanks for your reply. I looks like I don't need wp_query_reset -- Calling wp_reset_query is not necessary after using WP_Query or get_posts as these don't modify the main query object. Instead use wp_reset_postdata -- I replaced it with the wp_reset_postdata, but it doesn't "fix" the issue.

Comment: get_the_post_thumbnail() might be the culprit, as it can return false if it can't get the correct thumbnail ID. You should check that it's returning a string first before concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues.  Let's talk about them.

1. You need to put quotes around the key `count` for the width equation, i.e. `$atts['count'];`.
2. You want to use the escape sanitizers in WordPress instead of just `htmlentities`.
3. You need to reset the query before you returning.  Best practice is to place it right after the `foreach`.
4. Shortcodes must return and not echo.  They get processed with either `do_shortcode()` or when the content is processed.

### Revised Code

Here's the revised code which implements the above.  I tested this code in my sandbox site and it works without issue.

```
add_shortcode( 'v3grid', 'v3grid_shortcode_processing' );
/**
 * v3grid shortcode processor.  It builds the HTML markup for
 * the most recent posts and assembles them into a grid markup
 * structure.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $atts Array of user-defined attributes
 *
 * @return string
 */
function v3grid_shortcode_processing( $atts ) {

    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'count'       => 3,
            'link_to_all' => 'yes',
            'css_class'   => 'v3grid',
            'categories'  => '1',
        ), $atts, 'v3grid'
    );

    // Get list of recent posts
    $args = array(
        'numberposts' => (int) $atts['count'],
        'post_type'   => 'roundup',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
    if ( ! $recent_posts ) {
        return '<p>Sorry, there are no posts to display.</p>';
    }

    // Figure out width requirement for each grid item
    $width = 100 / (int) $atts['count'];

    // Container for row start
    $output = 'Start -> <div style="margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; box-sizing: border-box; position:relative; display:block;">';

    // Loop through posts
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $recent["ID"], 'full' );
        $url       = get_permalink( $recent["ID"] );

        $output .= '   1 - <div style="width:' . (int) $width . '%; float:left; padding:10px; display:block;">';
        $output .= '       2 - <div><img src="' . esc_url( $thumbnail ) . '" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>';
        $output .= '       3 - <div><a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '">' . esc_html( $recent["post_title"] ) . '</a></div>';
        $output .= '   4 - </div>';
    }
    wp_reset_query();

    $output .= 'End -> </div>';

    return $output;
}
```

### Now What?

Now you've fixed the problems in your shortcode function.  Okay, but you said the original problem was:  It works perfectly when you `echo` but not when you `return`.  That means something is filtering out your HTML text after you return it.

Right?  If the HTML is perfect when echoing but wonky when processed through the website and rendered out into the browser, then you know the remaining part of the problem is likely after your code above.

I'd start with looking at your plugin.  Make sure you are not doing something such filtering `the_content`.  Disable the rest of your plugin's code and see if the shortcode renders properly.

If that doesn't fix it, then disable all other plugins.  Does the problem go away?  Switch to a default WordPress theme. Does the problem go away?

This approach is what we call an elimination methodology.  You are eliminating all variables and possible contributors, stripping the site down to the bare bones in an effort to find the root cause.

As I said, it works without issue on my sandbox machine.  But my setup will not be the same as yours.  Stripping the site down to the bare essentials helps you to sniff out what is causing the problem.

### Tips for Improvement

Here is a list of improvements to help you too:

1. You do not need to include the default state elements with the arguments you pass to `wp_get_recent_posts()`.  Notice that I reduced them in the above code.
2. You want to validate if `wp_get_recent_posts` returns a falsey. That means there were no posts that meet your criteria.
3. Include the shortcode name when you do `shortcode_atts`.  While this is not contributing to your issue, it's a better practice to allow other developers access.
4. Use class attributes and move the inline styles into a stylesheet.

#### Separation of Concerns

It's a best practice to remove the HTML from the PHP business logic.  Place the HTML into a view file. Why? Separation of concerns.  It also improves readability.

Here's an example for you.

This is the view file. Let's call it `views/v3grid.php`.  Notice that it's native HTML, which makes it easier to read.

```
<!-- Start v3grid -->
<div style="margin:0 -10px 0 -10px; box-sizing: border-box; position:relative; display:block;">
<?php foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) :
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $recent["ID"], 'full' ); ?>
    <!-- v3grid item -->
    <div class="v3grid--item" style="width: <?php echo (int) $width; ?>%; float: left; padding: 10px; display: block;">
        <div class="v3grid--thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $thumbnail ); ?>" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div class="v3grid--entry-title">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( $recent["post_title"] ); ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- End v3grid --></div>
```

Then in your shortcode function, you replace this code like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'v3grid', 'v3grid_shortcode_processing' );
/**
 * v3grid shortcode processor.  It builds the HTML markup for
 * the most recent posts and assembles them into a grid markup
 * structure.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $atts Array of user-defined attributes
 *
 * @return string
 */
function v3grid_shortcode_processing( $atts ) {

    .. this all remains the same as above

    // Figure out width requirement for each grid item
    $width = 100 / (int) $atts['count'];

    ob_start();
    include( __DIR__ .'/views/v3grid.php' );
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    wp_reset_query();

    return $html;
}
```

Then you can pull out all of the inline styles and add them into an external stylesheet.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for taking time to help. Very cool. I'm not sure what is going, I've implemented your recommendations and I'm still having the same issue. I'll move the CSS out once I've got it working and your recommendation to remove the HTML... very smart, I'll also do that.

Comment: If I comment out this, it works... `$output .= '2 - <div><img src="'.esc_url($thumbnail).'" style="display:block; width:100%;"></div>';`

Comment: @InsuredApple You need to look at the value that's in `$thumbnail`.  Make sure there is a URL in that variable.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking, but when I echo them out, they look fine. Normal URLs... so strange.

Comment: Interesting.... this work: `$output .= '2 - <div>'.esc_url($thumbnail).'</div>';` but as soon as I add the img tag it breaks. This breaks it `$output .= '2 - <div><img src="'.esc_url($thumbnail).'"></div>';`

Comment: This means something is not happy after you return the shortcode back. It could be a lot of possibilities at this point.  One tip is to add an `alt` tag, as I know WordPress wants `alt` tags.  Then you need to put on your detective hat.  Disable all the plugins except yours.  Does the problem go away.  If yes, then it's one of those plugins.  Switch to a default theme. Repeat. Same problem? Look in your plugin. Are you filtering `the_content`?

Comment: Got it. I'm going to continue the dig. ;)

Comment: `get_the_post_thumbnail()` might be the culprit, as it can return false if it can't get the correct thumbnail ID. You should check that it's returning a string first before concatenating.

Comment: @Dre It could, but he says it works perfectly when echoing out. Wonky problem.

Comment: @hellofromTonya Wait, surely it must be a filter? Should try `global $wp_filter; print_r($wp_filter['the_content']);` and see what filters are in play.

Another good comprehensive answer by the way.

Comment: @Dre +1 as it has to be the filter for `the_content`.  You're right.  That's the only thing which make sense to me too.

Answer (score 0):

When writing [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), you `return` inside it's function, and to call it inside your .php files you use: `echo`[`do_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

Consider using just usual echoing function, unless it is supposed to be used by your plugin user's via dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I am a bit confused by your reply. I use a shortcode as [v3grid] and I return the $output variable. But return is causing issues.

Comment: Echo doesn't work for me, because when I echo out the string, it always shows as first element on the page.

Comment: OK, but how do you call your function?

Comment: It's done through a shortcode. I insert [v3grid] into the page as text and Wordpress then executes the function. I have an echo and return in the function (at the bottom) - using the same variable $output. Echo works, but return does not return the full $output.

Answer (score 0):

As [manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) says:

> If the shortcode produces a lot of HTML then ob_start can be used to capture output and convert it to a string[...]

So, your code have to use a echo and shall return the generated string:

```
function v3grid_func() {
    ob_start(); // open the buffer

    /**
       all your code
    **/

    echo $output; // as you did

    return ob_get_clean(); // return from buffer and clean the buffer
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if this is progress because the final output is still "broken". Using the echo $output and return ob_get_clean(); results in the code showing up where the shortcode is (that's good), but the output is still broken.

Comment: what's the version of your WP? There's a bug in 2.5. And others few tips which could correct your code as well

Comment: I'm on version 4.7 of Wordpress.